# How does Excel Service applications worked on Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel-services

I would like to know how to get my Excel Service applications on the Sharepoint Online started. As I am still quite new to this SharePoint Online environment and be working a lot on this environment most of time.

Hoping someone would like to give me a general information on this feature.

Thank you very much!

xxmfxx

Comment: Do you want general information or something else . Your question isnt quite clear ?

Comment: Would wish to know the usage on SharePoint online.

Comment: Apologize if the question was too vague.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "SharePoint Online 2013", just SharePoint Online. (It changes weekly.)

Excel Services are not supported in SharePoint Online, or SharePoint Server 2016 or later.

What are you wanting to do with Excel Services? There may be other solutions.

Comment: Then maybe would like to find out if I'm able to import an excel file into custom list directly.  
As I feel that It is a hassle to copy and paste my data into the custom list, one cell by one cell.
Hope you are able to understand.

Comment: Also, would like to find out some of the features in this Excel Services.

Comment: You can copy and paste multiple rows into the SharePoint Quick Edit view. Make sure only editable columns are displayed in the view. Select the data from Excel, copy, move to the last row of the Quick Edit view, select the entire row and the paste. I have pasted several thousand rows at a time. It's slow to process, but only a single operation for the user.

Comment: > "Also, would like to find out some of the features in this Excel Services"

Excel Services was introduced with SharePoint 2007 and removed from SharePoint 2016 and later. See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/excel-services-overview

Answer (score 0):

While exporting excel sheet table in sharepoint -

- Select the columns and rows of the sheet and insert table
- Then go to design tab and select export table to sharepoint list
- Give a list name and mention the site path then submit

It shall create a list in sharepoint , time taken would be = no of items in a table .

Hope this helps !! :)